# Bootstrap Touch Carousel with Webpack

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack

I am in the process of moving a legacy webapp over to run on some sort of frontend dependancy manager. In this instance im using Webpack and NPM.

I have been able to migrate 90% of the app over, however I am stuck on an issue with [bootstrap-touch-carousel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-touch-carousel).

It seems even though I have installed it via npm, I am still not able to call it via the normal require(./bootstrap-touch-carousel).

Are the some dependencies that need to be required differently? Or am I on the wrong track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import it with `require('bootstrap-touch-carousel')` because in this module [package.json there isn't main file](https://github.com/ixisio/bootstrap-touch-carousel/blob/master/package.json)

You must explicitly import distributed .js file by doing this:

```
require('bootstrap-touch-carousel/dist/js/bootstrap-touch-carousel')
```